# Interchange minimum and maximum for discrete sets

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, combinatorial-game-theory, discrete-optimization

I have a function $f$ which is linear in the first argument $x \in \mathcal{X}$, and quadratic in the second argument $y \in \mathcal{Y}$. The set $\mathcal{X}$ is countable, and the set $\mathcal{Y}$ is finite. I want to know under what conditions is the following equality true. The sets are bounded.

\begin{equation*}
\min_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} f(x, y) \stackrel{?}= \max_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \min_{x \in \mathcal{X}} f(x, y)
\end{equation*}

Comment: Does [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189338/when-min-max-max-min?rq=1) helps you? See, for instance, Royi's answer.

Comment: That is for continuous functions. I do not have continuity.