# How to prove that $\min_{x\in X} \max_{y\in Y} \{a^T x + b^T y + y^T Ax \} = \max_{y\in Y} \min_{x\in X} \{a^T x + b^T y + y^T Ax \}$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra

If $X := \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Px \leq p \right\}$ and $Y := \left\{ y \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid Qy \leq q \right\}$ are nonempty and bounded polyhedral sets, and if $a\in \mathbb{R}^n, b\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, how do we prove the following?

$$\min_{x \in X} \max_{y \in Y} \left\{ a^T x + b^T y + y^T Ax \right\} = \max_{y \in Y} \min_{x \in X} \left\{a^T x + b^T y + y^T Ax \right\}$$

I can prove that $\min_{x\in X} \max_{y\in Y} \{a^T x + b^T y + y^T Ax \} \geq \max_{y\in Y} \min_{x\in X}  \{a^T x + b^T y + y^T Ax \}$ by considering a specific $(x', y') \in X\times Y$.
Specifically, letting $f(x, y) = a^T x + b^T y + y^T Ax $, we have
\begin{align*}
  f(x', y') &\geq \min_{x\in X} f(x, y')\\
  \implies \max_{y\in Y} f(x', y) &\geq \max_{y\in Y} \min_{x\in X} f(x, y)\\
  \implies \min_{x\in X}\max_{y\in Y} f(x, y) &\geq \max_{y\in Y} \min_{x\in X} f(x, y).
\end{align*}

However, I am not sure how to continue to show the reverse inequality, namely to show that $\min_{x\in X} \max_{y\in Y} \{a^T x + b^T y + y^T Ax \} \leq \max_{y\in Y} \min_{x\in X}  \{a^T x + b^T y + y^T Ax \}$.

My intuition says we need to construct a dual LP and use weak duality, but that hasn't worked.
Could someone nudge me in the right direction? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This is too complex for me to answer on my own, but [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189338/when-min-max-max-min) and the associated answers might be helpful.